# Corrupted WD hard disk? Macbook Air says "hard disk not readable"

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility

So one night I finished editing a video and I was so excited that I got up and realised the hard disk was still connected to my Macbook Air. When I stood up, the hard disk was hanging on the Macbook Air for one second. When I realised the hard disk was hanging, I quickly sat down and moved the hard disk to an appropriate position. The hard disk was working for 10 mins and then I accidentally put my hand and applied a bit of pressure on top of the hard disk and heard a crackling noise. Since then,it just stopped working. So I force quit all my programs and when I tried to connect to my  hard disk to my Macbook Air, an error pop up saying "hard disk not readable.". I tried to connect the hard disk with a different USB cable but the problem was still not solved. I believe I may have corrupted my hard disk and I hope I'm able to repair it and get my files back. I read online that many people are also experiencing this issue with WD's hard disk. I also tried to use 3rd party recovery softwares but it won't solve the problem just yet because I can't even connect my hard disk to my  MacBook. I also tried connecting my hard disk to my Windows laptop, no luck. I also rebooted my MacBook air, no luck. My hard disk is a WD 1311B.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks,

Jeff

**Update**

I tried to reformat my hard disk but wasn't able to do so.

Comment: How hard did you press down to hear crackling noise?  But, once you let the "snap, crackle, and pop" out of a drive, it's pretty much a done deal.  Software can't fix a hardware problem.  However, there are services that specialize in **Hard Drive Recovery**  A Google search will get you a number of good results.

Comment: There was no pop or snap sound only a 1 second crackling noise and I'm 50% sure the hard disk is ok because I'm still able to see it on my windows laptop, but I just can't access or reformat it.

Comment: That was me being facetious.  The hard disk being recognized and being accessible are two completely different functions.  I have a crashed hard drive that gets properly recognized.  I can't read/write a single thing from/to it.

Comment: Did you managed to fix it? Because I've been trying everything.

Comment: I found this website http://www.datacent.com/hard_drive_sounds.php  quite interesting that my hard drive does not sound like that.

Comment: No.  It's toast  You can't DIY fix a hard drive failure.   However, I would check to see if it's under warranty.

Comment: I FIXED IT!. I didn't change the hardware parts or anything!. All I did was that when I clicked initialised in Disk Management, I clicked the second bullet point not the first!. After that, I just created a new volume and ran a recovery software on it. Done and dusted!

Answer (score 1):

I FIXED IT!. I didn't change the hardware parts or anything!. All I done was that I went on my Windows laptoo and when I clicked initialised in Disk Management, I clicked the second bullet point not the first!. After that, I just created a new volume and ran a recovery software on it. Done and dusted!